# css problems using percentage with inner elements making up equal percentages

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem I cannot figure out and it is just not making sense for me.

I have 1 container div with width set to 100%.
I have 5 divisions inside all with the same class name and 20% width.

For some reason it won't fit them in at 20%, but will fit them in at 19%? I have checked to see that there are no margins, borders or padding that could be interfering, but cannot find anything. I can't really show you an example because it's hard to replicate the problem (as it works elsewhere).

Has anybody experienced this before and have any suggestions?

Comment: I have not had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same sometimes. Be sure to have no margin padding or border on the divisions, the container, and the body. Make sure that your body is 100% wide too. If the problem is still there, put a little negative margin like `margin-left: - 2px;` on your 5 divisions

Answer (score 0):

This works fine and it sounds just like you are doing?

Do you have a link to the page you are working on?

```
<style>
    .blah{
        width: 20%;
        margin: 0;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<div style="width: 100%; ">
    <div class="blah" style="background-color: green;">
    </div>
    <div class="blah" style="background-color: green;">
    </div>
    <div class="blah" style="background-color: green;">
    </div>
    <div class="blah" style="background-color: green;">
    </div>
    <div class="blah" style="background-color: green;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block

can't believe this is a known problem

Comment: divs aren't inline-block by default (they're block-level elements). If you're explicitly setting them to inline-block, that should definitely be included in the description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the number of pixels that are available can't be evenly divided by the sizes specified. For example, if your overall width is 97 pixels, then setting 5 divs to each be 20% of that is going to be 19.4 pixels each, so their sizes will need to be rounded in some way. How that rounding is handled varies by browser. Some will always round down, some will always round up (causing them to not fit), and some will round some elements up and some elements down (causing them to no longer be exactly the same size, but they will fit and will add up to 100%)